# Nested Dictionary in swift

Tags: swift

I am having a hard time to achieve this kind of structure  for my dictionary, This is what i want to achieve:

```
{
  "document_requested": {
    "type": "endorsement"
  },
  "where_needed": "For employment",
  "copies": 3,
  "special_instructions": "Test instruction"
}
```

This is what I have so far

```
var params = [String:AnyObject]()

        params["where_needed"] = requestParams["where_needed"]
        params["copies"] = requestParams["number_of_copies"]
        params["special_instructions"] = requestParams["special_instructions"]
```

My problem now is how can I add this part

```
"document_requested": {
        "type": "endorsement"
      }
```

in my params variable.

Thank you very much

Comment: How is `requestParams` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it like this:

```
params["document_requested"] = ["type":"endorsement"]
```